# Custom metric for Keras in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I would like to create a custom metric in order to train a fully connected neural network in R. The issue is that I can not figure out how to pass the syntax to R tensorflow.
The desired function would be something like this:

```
fganancia   <- function(probs, data)
{
tbl <- as.data.table( list( "prob"=probs, "gan"= ifelse( data==1, 29250, -750 ) ) )
setorder( tbl, -prob )
tbl[ , gan_acum :=  cumsum( gan ) ]
gan <- max( tbl$gan_acum )
return(  gan  )
}
```

If this was a list, i would like to sort this list based on `y_prob` (`y_true` would be influenced by this sort). Then assign 2 different values to `y_true` depending its value (0 or 1) and finally calculate the cumulative sum and get the max value of it.

Is it possible to reproduce this in R tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by a long day of researching. This would be the equivalent code for keras tensorflow:

```
Ganancia<- custom_metric("Ganancia",function(y_true, y_pred) {

  
  weights = k_ones_like(y_true)
  loss = k_switch(k_equal(y_true,1), weights*29250, weights*(-750))
  values = tf$argsort(y_pred,axis = 0, direction='DESCENDING')
  ganancia = tf$gather(loss, values)
  ganancia=k_cumsum(ganancia, axis = 1)
  max=k_max(ganancia)
  

  
  return(max)
})
```